# R -- For loop using sprintf function in command system evaluation

Tags: r, batch-file, for-loop, printf, batch-processing

I have a number of files that I would like to run using a batch file that will be executed from R using a for loop. As an example, let's assume that I have 2 runs that I would like to execute:

```
runs <- c(102, 103)
```

The syntax for the system command requires that the batch file be specified first, followed by the input data file for the run (`102.txt` and `103.txt`) and the name of the output results file after the batch file has been executed (`102.res` and `103.res`).  I am attempting to run this using a for loop:

```
for (r in runs) {
   cmd <- sprintf('C:/example1/test.bat %d.txt %d.res', runs, runs)[1]
   print(eval(cmd))
   command: system(cmd)
}

[1] "C:/example1/test.bat 102.txt 102.res"
```

Unfortunately, this only executes the first run (`102`) and does not advance to the next run (`103`).  The R console displays the following warning:

```
Error in command:system(cmd) : NA/NaN argument
```

Thinking that this error is what is preventing R from advancing to the next run, I have attempted to use `options(warn = -1)` in the for loop:

```
for (r in runs) {
   options(warn = -1)
   cmd <- sprintf('C:/example1/test.bat %d.ctl %d.res', runs, runs)[1]
   print(eval(cmd))
   command: system(cmd)
   options(warn = 0)
}
```

Unfortunately, this continues to throw the same error.  For what it's worth, the output from my batch file (`102.res`) is exactly how I want it to be, I simply want to be able to bypass this error and continue on with the rest of my runs.  Any thoughts on how best to do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you expecting the line `command: system(cmd)` to be doing?  In R, `:` is a function for a general sequence.  You're basically saying you want a sequence from `command` to `system(cmd)` there, and hence the error.  Take a look at `4:10`, for example

Comment: where you have cmd ... runs, runs  should be cmd ... r, r. You are not using the loop variable, you are using the array.

Comment: Furthermore, that's an error not a warning.  There's a difference. Changing `options("warn")` won't do anything

Comment: Good job asking a clear question.  But you could have focused on the R part, with the printing of the command, and left out the system part.  Also, it may have been helpful to review, and include, the printout.

Comment: Also, R. Scriven point about the mixing of the command:system is valid.  You should try to post code that runs in R, otherwise the reviewers have to interpret what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's what you had

```
runs <- c(102, 103)
for (r in runs) {
  cmd <- sprintf('C:/example1/test.bat %d.txt %d.res', runs, runs)[1]
  print(eval(cmd))
#  command: system(cmd)
}
```

which outputs

```
[1] "C:/example1/test.bat 102.txt 102.res"
[1] "C:/example1/test.bat 102.txt 102.res"
```

try using the loop variable, r, instead of the array, runs, in the cmd <-... line

```
for (r in runs) {
   cmd <- sprintf('C:/example1/test.bat %d.txt %d.res', r, r)[1]  # <- change runs to r
   print(eval(cmd))
#  command: system(cmd)
}
```

output is

```
[1] "C:/example1/test.bat 102.txt 102.res"
[1] "C:/example1/test.bat 103.txt 103.res"
```